# Why is keras.Model.fit() transforming my boolean tensor into a float32 tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, input, model

I am building a custom keras model, where the inputs is a tuple, containing the features as a float32 tensor and a boolean tensor which i will later use as a mask in another subclassed layer. Now my problem is, that when simply calling the model on the inputs, everything behaves like expected, but as soon as I put the input tensors into a dataset and call the fit() method, the boolean tensor is somehow casted into a float32 tensor, which is not what i want, and which I don't understand why. May anyone shed some light on this?

I am using tensorflow 2.15.0, keras 2.15.0 and python 3.11.5

Here is the code to hopefully reproduce the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# define subclassed model
class TM(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TM, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        features = inputs[0]
        input_mask = inputs[1] # here its already casted to float32 dtype, but should be bool
        print("features:")
        print(features)
        print()

        print("input mask:")
        print(input_mask)
        print("-"*100)
        return features

# instantiate model and compile   
tm = TM()
tm.compile(loss="mean_squared_error")

# creating some fake data
feature_tensor = tf.random.uniform(shape=[1,8])
boolean_tensor = tf.fill(dims=[1, 8], value=True)

# put into tensorflow dataset
tds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((feature_tensor, boolean_tensor))

# shows the correct dtypes before handing to the model
print("ds element spec:")
print(tds.element_spec)
print("-"*100)

# calling the model on the inputs directly
print("Input when called directly on the model:")
print(tm((feature_tensor, boolean_tensor)))
print("-"*100)

# calling the model on the inputs via the dataset and fit method
tm.fit(tds)
```

While it outputs as described above:

```
ds element spec:
(TensorSpec(shape=(8,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(8,), dtype=tf.bool, name=None))
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Input when called directly on the model:
features:
tf.Tensor(
[[0.7957325  0.694777   0.1260978  0.5917362  0.17017555 0.8500334
  0.23767495 0.88851535]], shape=(1, 8), dtype=float32)

input mask:
tf.Tensor([[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]], shape=(1, 8), dtype=bool)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tf.Tensor(
[[0.7957325  0.694777   0.1260978  0.5917362  0.17017555 0.8500334
  0.23767495 0.88851535]], shape=(1, 8), dtype=float32)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
features:
Tensor("tm_7/strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)

input mask:
Tensor("tm_7/strided_slice_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 66ms/step - loss: 0.0417
```

As one can see when the model is called without the fit() method the boolean tensor is still as is, a boolean tensor. But when called inside the fit() method type of the tensor suddenly becomes float32 ...

Comment: You overwrite the call method yourself, and in it you don't transform the data, so it is still `bool`. For the fit part, tensorflow needs the data to be `float32` (or float16 for mixed/low precision) to use efficiently in computation. The prediction output of the model is in `float32`, so it transforms the labels to be the same dtype to prevent type missmatching.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, I understand this as changing the input to a nested tuple, where the first index into the tuple holds another tuple containing the features and the 'input_mask', and the second index holding the float32-labels should solve the problem, because tf expects the second index to be the labels. Testing this, it doesn't, so did I get you wrong?

Comment: In a sense this is more of a discussion question, your variables are converted for efficient and fast computing.